# Why the name "Behavior" in BehaviorSubject in RX?

Tags: system.reactive

I'm curious, why do you think they used the name "Behavior" for the BehaviorSuject object in Ractive Extensions?

note: a behavior subject returns the last value (or the init vaue) as the first value to any subscriber.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In the world of **functional reactive programming**, a *behavior* is a value that changes over time. This is exactly what a BehaviorSubject represents: when you subscribe you get the current value, and then you can continue to observe the changes. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_reactive_programming.